# Remove multiple characters from a list if they are next to each other in Scheme

Tags: duplicates, scheme, racket

I have to make a Dr. Racket program that removes letters from a list if they are following the same letter as itself. For example: (z z f a b b d d) would become 
(z f a b d). I have written code for this but all it does is remove the first letter from the list. 
Can anyone help?

```
#lang racket 
(define (remove-duplicates x)
(cond ((null? x)
     '())
    ((member (car x) (cons(car(cdr x)) '())))
     (remove-duplicates (cdr x))
    (else
     (cons (car x) (remove-duplicates (cdr x))))))

(define x '( b c c d d a a))
(remove-duplicates x)
```

Comment: The interaction window is your friend. Enter `(cons (car (cdr '(a b a))) '())` and ponder the result.

Comment: You might want to accept/upvote an answer if it sufficed to help solve your problem. That's the best way to show your gratitude, as comments à la "Thank you" are discouraged here, since they don't really contribute anything to the topic at hand. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(define (remove-dups x)
   (cond
     [(empty? x) '()]
     [(empty? (cdr x))  (list (car x))]
     [(eq? (car x) (cadr x))  (remove-dups (cdr x))]
     [else  (cons (car x) (remove-dups (cdr x)))]))
```

`(cadr x)` is short for `(car (cdr x))` in case you didn't know.

Also, pattern matching makes list deconstruction often much more readable. In this case not so much, but it's still better than the other version:

```
(define (rmv-dups x)
  (match x
    [(list)  (list)]
    [(list a)  (list a)]
    [(cons a (cons a b))  (rmv-dups (cdr x))]
    [__  (cons (car x) (rmv-dups (cdr x)))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem will be simpler if you introduce a helper function.

I recommend something like this (where angle brackets mean you need to fill out the details):

```
(define (remove-duplicates x)
  (cond
    [ <x is empty>                             '()]  ; no duplicates in empty list
    [ <x has one element>                      x]    ; no duplicates in a list with one element
    [ <first and second element in x is equal> (cons (car x) (remove-from-front (car x) (cdr x)))]
    [else                                      (cons (car x) (remove-duplicates (cdr x)))]))

(define (remove-from-front e x)
  (cond
    [ <x is empty>                  '()]                 ; e is not the first element of x
    [ <e equals first element of x> (remove-from-front e (cdr x))] ; skip duplicate
    [else                           (remove-duplicates x)]))       ; no more es to remove
```