# how to remove neighbouring duplicate in a list?

Tags: scheme, racket

How to remove neighbouring duplicate in a list using scheme programming??

For example.

```
(2 2 4 6 7 7 32 32 4)
```

becomes

```
(2 4 6 7 32 4)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052559/simple-issue-in-dr-racket-syntax/33053923#33053923

Comment: What do you have so far?